# How do I kill an incapacitated colonist?

Tags: rimworld

A colonist that lost her leg is now incapacitated and I want to euthanize her, how do I do this?

Comment: You monster....

Comment: Drop her into the Aperture Science "Emergency Intelligence Incinerator"...

Comment: You could give her prosthetic limbs instead. Colonists are precious resources, nothing gets done without them!

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to kill incapacitated colonists or prisoners.

On the health tab, select the Operations sub tab and you can schedule a number of operations. To simply kill the patient, select Euthanize. If you're feeling diabolical, you can also harvest body parts before putting them out of their misery. Removing a lung and a kidney will not kill the patient, assuming they are starting with two. Removing any other part (heart, liver) will result in the death of the patient.

You can also select a colonist who has a gun, and fire at the ground where the person is standing/lying.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just figured out. I had this colonist stuck to a medical bed with no legs and was receiving decent treatment and food, I just converted the whole room to a prison and the colonist fell out of bed and a message appeared that she needed to be rescued. I just let her starve to death.

Comment: You heartless monster... xD

Comment: I know there can be a ethics or moral discussion right here, but it's only a videogame about survival and I was wasting valuable food on her. I guess I could have sent her out to space with the whole building a ship part of the game but I don't know if once I have built that she could be taken to a cryo-sleep chamber.

Comment: There could be a discussion about this but I am not better. Sometimes I use my colonists as baits for bandits :P

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of killing a fellow colonist would be to draft another colonist, give him/her a gun and force them to shoot the incapacitated colonist. Or you could use an improvised turret and force attack the colonist.